# why `setConnectionRequestTimeout` doesn't stop my 1 min get request?

Tags: java, http, request, timeout, client

I have this code:

```
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(40 * 1000)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(40 * 1000)
            .setSocketTimeout(40 * 1000)
            .build();
    client = HttpClientBuilder
            .create()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .build();
}
```

and

```
    try {

        Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        response = client.execute(new HttpGet(routingRequestUrl));
        stopWatch.stop();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        answer.errorMsg = e.getMessage();
        answer.latency =  null;
    }
```

when my client configuration is as doesn't contain `.setSocketTimeout(40 * 
1000)` - the stopWatch shows request can take more then 1 minute.

It happens when I try `setConnectTimeout` and `setConnectionRequestTimeout` each alone or all together.

Why is only `.setSocketTimeout(40 * 1000)` effectively checks timeout 40 seconds? and the other alone not?

These are the prints:

`Read timed out`

`Timeout waiting for connection from pool`

Is the first triggered by `setConnectionRequestTimeout` and the second by `setSocketTimeout` ?

Comment: See also [understanding URLConnection.setReadTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554342/understanding-urlconnection-setreadtimeout)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.html

```
getConnectionRequestTimeout()
```

Returns the timeout in milliseconds used when requesting a connection from the connection manager.

```
getConnectTimeout()
```

Determines the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.

```
getSocketTimeout()
```

Defines the socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) in milliseconds, which is the timeout for waiting for data or, put differently, a maximum period inactivity between two consecutive data packets).

__

So, the first one, **connectionRequestTimeout** happens when you have a pool of connections and they are all busy, not allowing the connection manager to give you one connection to make the request.

**connectTimeout** happens when establishing the connection. For instance while doing the tcp handshake.

**socketTimeout** like the description says, is the timeout while waiting for data. Usually happens when your server is slow.

Comment: so if i want to terminate request that didn't return after 40 seconds I should use socketTimeout only ?

Comment: @EladBenda2 unfortunately not, you will need create you're own wrapper that does an overall that could encompass the `connectionRequestTimeout`, `connectTimeout` and `socketTimeout`. The `socketTimeout` is the time in seconds between receiving bytes of data, so as long as you are receiving data it won't timeout.