# Read timed out on Spring RestTemplate call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have an API which returns a json it is of type GET method. Since it is GET, when I open the URL in browser it works fine and renders the json, however, upon using RestTemplate to retrieve the json it fails.

Could you please provide a way to read below API.

API URL: https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY

Spring Boot Rest Template Call:

```
final String uri = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Map result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Map.class);
```

Error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:448) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:823) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:746) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: If you have any beans configured for `RestTemplate`,`RequestFactory` to make your API calls you will want tp ost it here. By default there are no timeouts set on `RestTemplate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the WebClient from webflux instead:

**- Add the dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**- Create the POJO**

```
@Data
public class Root {
    private Records records;
    private Filtered filtered;

    @Data
    public static class PE {
        private int strikePrice;
        private String expiryDate;
        private String underlying;
        private String identifier;
        private int openInterest;
        private int changeinOpenInterest;
        private double pchangeinOpenInterest;
        private int totalTradedVolume;
        private double impliedVolatility;
        private double lastPrice;
        private double change;
        private double pChange;
        private int totalBuyQuantity;
        private int totalSellQuantity;
        private int bidQty;
        private double bidprice;
        private int askQty;
        private double askPrice;
        private double underlyingValue;
    }

    @Data
    public static class CE {
        private int strikePrice;
        private String expiryDate;
        private String underlying;
        private String identifier;
        private int openInterest;
        private int changeinOpenInterest;
        private int pchangeinOpenInterest;
        private int totalTradedVolume;
        private int impliedVolatility;
        private int lastPrice;
        private double change;
        private double pChange;
        private int totalBuyQuantity;
        private int totalSellQuantity;
        private int bidQty;
        private double bidprice;
        private int askQty;
        private double askPrice;
        private double underlyingValue;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Datum {
        private int strikePrice;
        private String expiryDate;
        private PE PE;
        private CE CE;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Records {
        private List<String> expiryDates;
        private List<Datum> data;
        private String timestamp;
        private double underlyingValue;
        private List<Integer> strikePrices;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Filtered {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

**- Let WebClient make the call**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MultipleConfigurationPropertiesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MultipleConfigurationPropertiesApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
        return args -> {
            WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://www.nseindia.com")
                    .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                            .codecs(configurer -> configurer
                                    .defaultCodecs()
                                    .maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024))
                            .build())
                    .build();

            Mono<Root> result = client.get()
                    .uri("/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(Root.class);

            System.out.println(result.block());
        };
    }
}
```

You have to tune the buffer size as the request result is huge.

Also, you might want to consider using non-blocking/stream solution to handle this.

Comment: Thank you @Christian, using WebClient did the trick. Any specific reason why it didn't work with RestClient? due to https url?

Comment: @JavaCodeNet I am getting response like strikePrice=18600, expiryDate=25-Jan-2024, PE=null, CE=null, not sure why PE and CE are null

Answer (score 0):

I tested the API GET request in a browser moments ago, and the results are highly nested.  You are attempting to retrieve the results into a `Map` object, but you are not specifying the types for `Key` or `Value`, the latter of which is likely a `Map` or `List` itself.

First, determine if you can retrieve the raw JSON results into a `String`.

```java
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
```

If this works, then you will know that the GET request is working via `RestTemplate`.  If not, you can troubleshoot the default [timeout settings](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestFactory.html) and adjust based on how long you observe the network response to take in the browser, for instance.

Assuming you can retrieve the raw JSON results into a `String`, then your next step will be to analyze the "shape" of the JSON data returned.  If you want the JSON results converted into a POJO, you will have to create a class (or set of classes) that match the "shape" of the JSON data.

```
records:
    
  expiryDates   […]
  data  […]
  timestamp "31-Aug-2020 15:30:00"
  underlyingValue   11387.5
  strikePrices  […]

filtered:   
  data  […]
  CE    
    totOI   367314
    totVol  4988131
  PE    
    totOI   261696
    totVol  5501580
```

Answer (score 0):

Read timeouts like this occur when you reach the max period of inactivity between consecutive data packets. You'll have to provide a read timeout configured ClientHttpRequestFactory to your RestTemplate when you initialize it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713767/spring-rest-template-readtimeout) is one example of doing this.

You may also want to consider making your RestTemplate into a Bean if you have to make more of these long running requests. This way you don't have to configure this again each time.