# Springboot: how to fetch data from NSE using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http-headers, resttemplate

I am trying to fetch data from NSE using the below code

```
    final String url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=FINNIFTY";

    Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String nsit = "nsit=wes0AwEKvByjMnl-g3c3IxnU;";
    String nseappid = "nseappid=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhcGkubnNlIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpLm5zZSIsImlhdCI6MTY0MDI2NzQ2MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQwMjcxMDYwfQ.-ehe3ZqLvItmdZ4j3A3aQYhY6kU4Bue0sBOFa5LA4ak;";
    String bmsv = "bm_sv=E5E08013E7D777B541D939ECF19145D7~YAAQ1SdzaPz0Dm+HAQAAj6/VgxN/Q4sEL9dnAzIGprsBvfEeCH/zwVWkga6fWsb9u1vqHNn0A0CoxdO4pjo1TKRXhAeUrzs+gkcJjyHA9MtsvkciVf6ZEpbhFbcJHRsYxFnjav24oIUCDkEse6ws0lWOaFJm7N6ixnraD+hJDtU01qDdKdErRbjcgNrK1Q01zSpVwq1YbmEwIpeE8gFBnHu/bxlsxhFzdVHaXFtzQ7wfPWKgp4qKuXytrxwDtA1wpJ4=~1";

    String cookies =nsit + nseappid +bmsv;
    headerMap.put("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
    headerMap.put("referer", "https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain");
    headerMap.put("accept-encoding", "identity");
    headerMap.put("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36");
    headerMap.put("cookie", cookies);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    System.out.println("about to call nse");
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url,
            GET,
            new HttpEntity<>(headerMap),
            String.class);
    System.out.println("finished call nse");
    System.out.println(response);
```

I am getting "about to call nse" in console but after that it's long waiting time. no error but no response as well. it seems like it's issue with headers but not sure how to fix it.

on adding logs

```
2023-04-15T17:50:27.943+05:30 DEBUG 14552 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY
2023-04-15T17:50:28.170+05:30 DEBUG 14552 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2023-04-15T17:50:28.186+05:30 DEBUG 14552 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{referer=https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9, cookie=_ga=GA1.1.1569929550.1680665131; defaultLang=en; AKA_A2=A; nsit=GoqcdfzwhFsjo9BmYC-6pW6V; nseappid=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhcGkubnNlIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpLm5zZSIsImlhdCI6MTY4MTU2MDY3NCwiZXhwIjoxNjgxNTY3ODc0fQ.9kjpVJD3OUvzX2lFBAjuMtacVyZ8Nx5eyHrWt9bB90A; bm_mi=E59DD6D95B6D984F88F7D8FDBE8DBC55~YAAQdSdzaLsG5nGHAQAAEqHThBMO3B4EiZ/BYywOjqpeP4PjlFJ6Eob2KgtwLE018axXk1/e1LhJ6lNzs/hLKLetmG6qj//xrxwL6hN8POajY94JBcJ9oUIDj5p11NH788ZzomJU8q6YqcyfLWqb9o9m92PCxrmf7bgxSTfdv/EvYmRf9eGpc24Jd2HeJUt7zV5amT/rFjQgNzoLADtsUGha7tSkS006wN/qTwVgvX7N0sxM2VvmnH8QhpZLt3cgSNwZUfRVzQf0V0wbgMd8CZXNzrKEZbS2I5U/zK/8KcZHbtUMaYwIhHsgPg4W2vznPPHSsVKoy+8urVg=~1; ak_bmsc=A483AE3F73E34D9E070999585E9599A4~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQdSdzaKgH5nGHAQAAv8nThBOaWt3ZIw4Ve/n0fkQTznBywcMT2biLMl3Ut+46a8gW8WAJGihI56hPpQGAZcn622s/t5aX5T72k8F6Enc53cnuUYMER2QkhP6Xn0X9u+z8ee1mUrsQ+DP7QpDJxrGaDBDTf/Wx96ioNISNeTsCXspz3Uvsv9K1gRSA8H9Ahbs66mcEGYCPUdptS3ZqS078fxLYco00kl4B/FosPPgOeIzMJfhiJsnBmR495puUTnVl+tLHYqhXTO7y8YOlvbNWGqXQ2TyKlXaShjLkOz01HizZLpobB/R2tmAAnwX7PaLDtgsu4tQF/U35UCYdU8+4xzftzX34aB1e3HZTi2nZgVS91pzyxjTjo5xE785n96SIgLESEVyy7Ccp7WwffdwbwMIVJyRVQkJbXYbf7AYynF2cmE4uDC3k; RT="z=1&dm=nseindia.com&si=de8cce89-1ec7-45df-bb44-ee99440306f7&ss=lghxt4ey&sl=1&tt=205&bcn=//684d0d45.akstat.io/&ld=3h0&nu=kpaxjfo&cl=1b4h"; _ga_PJSKY6CFJH=GS1.1.1681560676.28.1.1681560735.1.0.0; bm_sv=99CE5413752CA0E1E86514D062274698~YAAQrCdzaPqaV1GHAQAAoo/UhBPT+3H6G8vI1AEnvhCDhMWX8Bm+NmXlVBkvGOzv0hGhK1nxvClrGboOZuZaEmGfcYq9X/a6A0dxm56oXJPDRhtQ3fsrmzHvzXy3cmxagXDuW7TKLQFekUkHRIbLgTVuABeQIUvUY+e2YUoCATSpL7js4RQrqc9tpTyXVFuyzOOvXxDXmvTRalrEFS4XFSn4COToXHYU2K2uIJQ1ZsbHdcJBCPESqVpkJHR7vdofI0pH~1, :path=/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36}] with org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
```

Please help.

Comment: Call NSE with Postman. Copy the working curl (in Postman, on the right under ‘</>’) into the question.

Comment: the response is too big see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678089/read-timed-out-on-spring-resttemplate-call

Comment: I used the feign client and now i am getting response, but difficult to understand this behaviour