# Stop / Interrupt the long running request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have a scenario-  Service A calls Service B by a HTTP GET request.

Service A ---> Service B

Service B at times, takes more than 2 minutes to return the result since it sometimes has to process a lot.

**I want to know how to do this by Spring Boot Rest Template.**

Service A is using Spring Boot Rest Template to call Service B. How can RestTemplate be programmed to kill a request when Service B takes more time than specified ? What I want to know is how can I stop/Interrupt the request in Service A if it takes more than 30 seconds to complete.

Also Is it possible to use @Retry annotation of  Resilience4J to retry if we do not get a response within 30 seconds. Service B is notoroious , there are high chances when we retry , it gives a reponse quicker than 2 minutes.

Comment: Set a connection and read time in yoru configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such scenario, I would suggest you to customise your restTemplate bean something like below:

```
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate() {

CloseableHttpClient client=HttpClients.createDefault();

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory req
        =new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
        req.setConnectionRequestTimeout(30000);
        req.setReadTimeout(30000);
        req. setConnectTimeout(30000);
return new RestTemplate(req);
}
```

So basically, you are setting timeouts in your restTemplate so that it will timeout & don't wait for default timeout setting.

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is adding a readTimeout(). For more info about readTimeout and connectionTimeout check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069382/what-is-the-difference-between-connection-and-read-timeout-for-sockets).

For setting the readTimeout in RestTemplate take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45715580/8363012

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks .