# Setting Timeout in URL Connection - Force Server to Finish Reading Data with Method Similar to HttpURLConnection.setReadTimeout()

Tags: java, connection, timeout, httpurlconnection

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24554342), the method `HttpURLConnection.setReadTimeout()` allows you to set the max amount of time to wait for server to **START** reading data from input stream - as stated by Oracle:

> A SocketTimeoutException can be thrown when reading from the returned
>   input stream if the read timeout expires before data is available for
>   read.

It does not allow you to set timeout to force server to **FINISH** reading data within a specific amount of time

My question is:

Is there a way to set a timeout to force server to finish reading data within a specified amount of time or is this at all not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a `timeout`, as per your requirement, on a `HttpURLConnection`.
However you could mitigate the situation using a separate `Thread`.

Get an `ExecutoreService`

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

Submit your `Callable<T>` task, where `T` is the data type you'll return after reading from the `HttpURLConnection` data stream.

```
final Future<T> result = executor.submit(new HttpTask());
```

You'll get a `Future<T>`, which represent the outcome of your task.
Now, use the `Future#get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` method.

```
try {
   final T value = result.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (final TimeoutException e) {
   result.cancel(true);
}
```

In that case, If more than 10 seconds passes, a `TimeoutException` will be thrown and you'll be able to abruptly end your task.

Comment: I'm already using ExecutorService in my application. However, calling result.cancel(true); will NOT terminate the underlying connection/thread. I'm trying to close/terminate connection in the underlying thread precisely for this reason when connection is ongoing for too long. So this would not address my problem.

Comment: @S.O.S you may want to handle an InterruptedException and close the connection accordingly.

Comment: @S.O.S and by the way, you can pass an HttpURLConnection as constructor parameter to your Callable task, and close it inside the catch block if necessary.